# Should setting an image src to data URL be available immediately?

Tags: javascript, html, image, data-uri

Consider the following (fragile) JavaScript code:

```
var img = new Image;
img.src = "data:image/png;base64,..."; // Assume valid data

// Danger(?) Attempting to use image immediately after setting src
console.log( img.width, img.height );
someCanvasContext.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );

// Danger(?) Setting onload after setting src
img.onload = function(){ console.log('I ran!'); };
```

**The Question(s)**

- Should the image width and height be correct immediately?
- Should the canvas draw work immediately?
- Should the `onload` callback (set after the src was changed) be invoked?

**Experimental Tests**
I created a [simple test page](http://phrogz.net/tmp/img_via_dataurl.html) with similar code. In Safari my first tests, both by opening the HTML page locally (`file:///` url) and loading it from my server, showed everything working: the height and width is correct, the canvas draw works, *and* the `onload` also fires.

In Firefox v3.6 (OS X), loading the page after launching the browser shows that the height/width is not correct immediately after setting, `drawImage()` fails. (The `onload` handler does fire, however.) Loading the page again, however, shows the width/height being correct immediately after setting, and `drawImage()` working. It would appear that Firefox caches the contents of the data URL as an image and has it available immediately when used in the same session.

In Chrome v8 (OS X) I see the same results as in Firefox: the image is not available immediately, but takes some time to asynchronously 'load' from the data URL.

In addition to experimental proof of what browsers the above does or does not work, I'd really love links to specs on how this is supposed to behave. So far my Google-fu has not been up to the task.

**Playing It Safe**
For those who don't understand why the above might be dangerous, know that you should use images like this to be safe:

```
// First create/find the image
var img = new Image;

// Then, set the onload handler
img.onload = function(){
  // Use the for-sure-loaded img here
};

// THEN, set the src
img.src = '...';
```

Comment: You definitely need to set `onload` before setting the `src`.  But if the load event sometimes fires in the current constellation, then setting the "data" URI is indeed asynchronous - which would surprise me. Interesting!

Comment: Is it not safer to assume that no, to pump a timeout and continue after the browser gets a chance to redraw itself ?

Comment: @mP Yes, it certainly is; I edited my question to make this clear a scant 5 minutes before your comment :) However, this does not invalidate the question. Assuming that the behavior in Chrome and FF is permissible—not a bug—then it is vital, in fact, to play it safe.

Comment: @Pekka See my 'answer' below; IE9 requires onload to be set before setting src, but no other browser does. (!) Surprising indeed.

Comment: @phrogz     Hi, Phrogz, this functionality is very important to me; however, on Android Browser (the latest version now), assigning dataURL to an image source just can't work properly even by your  "Playing It Safe" method.
Could you give me more suggestion?

Comment: @Stallman According to [this Android bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7901) it appears that `toDataURL()` was not properly implemented until recently. Have you first confirmed that you _have_ a valid data URL? Secondly, you should post this as a question, not as a comment to a largely unrelated question.

Comment: @Phrogz         Well... I got it... I will post a question in these days...  Thank u!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As no one has yet found any specifications about how this is *supposed* to behave, we will have to be satisfied with how it *does* behave. Following are the results of my tests.

```
            | is image data usable right  | does onload callback set after src
            |     after setting src?      |   is changed still get invoked?
------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------
Safari  5   |             yes             |                  yes                
------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------
Chrome  8   | **no** (1st page load), but |                  yes                
FireFox 3.6 |  yes thereafter (cached)    |                                     
------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------
IE8         |    yes (32kB data limit)    |                  yes         
------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------
IE9b        |             yes             |                 **no**              
------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------
```

In summary:

- You cannot assume that the image data will be available right after setting a data-uri; you must wait for the `onload` event.
- Due to IE9, you cannot set the `onload` handler after setting the `src` and expect it to be invoked.
- The recommendations in ***"Playing it Safe"*** (from the question above) are the only way to ensure correct behavior.

If anyone can find specs discussing this, I will happily accept their answer instead.

Comment: Thanks for the research you did here. I've been struggling with the possibility of forcing this behavior for an offline webapp where I need to report using canvas, so I dug in a bit more. The living WHATWG spec actually does call out the cached case as synchronous, and the non-cached case as asynchronous. Check out step 7 in the src section of the spec found here: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/embedded-content-1.html#attr-img-src. It appears if the image is in the Document's "list of available images" it completes synchronously, or that's how I read it.

Comment: @Phrogz At what stage or document state did you conduct that test? I am observing Safari 5.1 to have the Chrome behavior, but that's before the `window.load` event. Were your tests made after load or before? Do you remember?

Answer (score 7):

After giving control back to the browser's rendering engine, the test reports `true` in FF 4b9 and Chromium 8.0.552.237. I modified these parts:

```
img.onload = function(){   // put this above img.src = …
    document.getElementById('onload').innerHTML = 'yes';
};
img.src = img_src;
…
window.setTimeout(function () {   // put this inside setTimeout
    document.getElementById('wh').innerHTML = (img.height==img.width) && (img.height==128);
}, 0);
```

**Update:** Yes, I understand this 'answer' is more like a comment, but just wanted to point it out. And after testing I get reproducible results:

- without `setTimeout`, in both browsers I get `false` the first time I open the page and `true` only after hitting <kbd>F5</kbd>. After explicitly clearing the cache both say `false` again after reloading.
- with `setTimeout` the width/height test always evualuates to `true`.

In both cases the image doesn't show up the first time, only after reloading the page.

Comment: Are you telling me that without these changes you are seeing 'failures' in FF and Chromium? My question isn't how to make this work—clearly setting `onload` before `src` and only referencing the image in the callback will work. My question is whether there exist specs describing how this ought to work.