# Setting img src to a data url via work does not work in IE8?

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer-8, data-uri

When I [attempt to set an image to use a data url](http://phrogz.net/tmp/img_via_dataurl.html) via JavaScript *(from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776670/should-setting-an-image-src-to-dataurl-be-available-immediately))*, it does not appear to work in IE8.

The page in that first link has: `<img id="foo" src="alphaball.png">`
On line 25, this JavaScript code executes: `document.getElementById('foo').src = img_src;`

On all other browsers (including IE9b) this successfully changes the image from the alphaball to a picture of my head. On IE8, I see the alphaball very briefly, and then it is replaced with a missing image icon.

Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround for using data urls with IE8 and JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internet Explorer versions before 9 do not support data URLs. There's an alternative mechanism that apparently kind-of works.

*edit* — actually I'm wrong; IE8 will support them as long as they're less than 32KB.

*edit again* — ok I found [the article](http://www.phpied.com/mhtml-when-you-need-data-uris-in-ie7-and-under/) I was thinking about concerning the "MHTML" thing from Microsoft.

Comment: Ah, silly me. I forgot about the 32kB limit, and the data in that example appears to be slightly over. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the article on phpied.com :)
I am trying to replicate what the article describes, but using inline CSS instead of an external CSS file. However, I cannot make it work :(
I have opened a question about it here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280977/inline-images-in-html-for-ie8