# jqplot to image not working on IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, jqplot

i have been searching for  Jqplot image convertion and i have found this

**IE 6 – 8 are supported through Google’s excanvas.js library** in the following link

http://piwik.org/blog/2011/06/piwik-innovative-with-javascript-canvas-chart-and-contributing-by-jqplot-creator/

but still im facing the same problem . i couldnot convert jqplot to image in IE7

can any one show some working example ?

**updated**

Using excanvas I can render the chart but i want to make it as image . I can convert(Export) the  chart into image in chrome , FF , and IE 10 only but not in IE<9 .Is there any way to do this . can you kindly help me ?

```
<div id="chart1" style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px; width:600px; height:300px;"></div>

<div id="imgChart1"></div>
```

**updated**

i have placed my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sornalingam/uGWnL/155/

kindly help me plz

Comment: Please post in more clearer details I can see that the graph was rendered in the form of Image in IE 9 and 8  and 7 I don't have 6 to test for. Please confirm the image problem is still there or solved. thank you

Comment: @MarmiK i have updated the post kindly see it and help me

Comment: I have checked the provided link in IE8 and 7 it was working fine by my side, if not working on your side please add this two lines in head tag first in meta and first in script tag <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" contant="IE=edge" />


<!--[if lt IE 9]> <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script> <![endif]-->

Comment: @MarmiK can you kindly post your code either here or jfiddle

Comment: ya sure ... i will update now

Comment: @MarmiK i ave updated the code can you help me out

Comment: I have posted answer you are missing doctype in top and meta data in head tag

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `excanvas` does not have support for ImageData functions, so you cannot get the image date like you can do with native `canvas`.

The only polyfill for canvas, that i know, which  supports this is [FlashCanvas Pro](http://flashcanvas.net/docs/canvas-api).
But i neither can tell you if it works with `jqplot` nor can i tell you if it performs well, because i have never used it.

**EDIT**
Based on your edited question:
With this: `var imgElem = $('<img/>').attr('src',imgData);` you set a data url.
But data url are not support for IE 7 and older, and for IE 8 the data url is limited to `32 KB` which would be most likely be a problem if you create a larger image with jqplot.

**EDIT**
Based on the comment, that the client should be able to download the image:
If - as i said i don't know - the Pro version of FlashCanvas can create a data url reliable. You could think over doing a `POST` (this is required because `GET` request are also limited in size) of that data url to your server. On the server you can create an image out of that data, store it and submit the url to that temporary image as a response of the post. Then you could use this url for the image. This is for sure not an optimal solution but at least a workaround until you find something that works better.

For posting the data you could use `jquery.post` and return a `json` formatted response with the url to the temporary image.

With [modernizr.com](http://modernizr.com/) you could check if the browser supports `dataurl` and only do this fallback if it does not support it. For `IE 8` you probably need to do further checks.

Comment: thanks for your kind reply.. i have tried this already but i couldnot convert

Comment: @Backtrack added an edit note based on your edited question. Why do you need it as image?

Comment: since many of our customers using IE<9 so we need to give them

Comment: @Backtrack What i wanted to know was, why you need it as image (why the diagram created in `chart1` is not sufficient for you)?

Comment: yes . coz my clients need to save it in their local machine as .jpeg/.png any format

Answer (score 1):

In the case of IE, each IE runs with separate mind,

even jQuery and Plugins do not work with IE sometimes, this seems same..

the Basic problem is support provided by IE for JavaScript is not consistent throughout versions.

Few Minor things that you need to change.

you already have specified `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`

further you need to specify meta to define its type.

that guides IE to identify the content type.. (dumb IE)

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" contant="IE=edge" />
```

Please define all meta after this Meta TAG.

and after that here come this code that you have to define before you start defining scripts.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> 
    <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script> 
<![endif]-->
```

This makes thing moreover under control.

Please change this and see the difference.

Update: If there is something related to plotting specific,

on this [Example link](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/area.html) when you click on plot Image it generates image with code like this.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
```

so that is nothing but a image's base64 string that is embedded under `<img` tag.

Also see the updated [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/ddK5E/2/) and reply on that too :)

Edit : DataURL in IE 8

Please refer [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807622/setting-img-src-to-a-data-url-via-work-does-not-work-in-ie8) how this will work or alternate to make it work. although the way is not easy but a work around with help of MHTML(Mime based html), CSS and the constraint is 32 KB of size. Please watch out if some other work around is there..

And below IE8 there is not support for data URI.

Edit: New Link found

There is a trick using CSS file and calling it as MHTML Mime type.
[Link to Page](http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-data-uris-in-all-browsers)

I think this will help,(Limitations will be same for size constraint.

If any concern please reply

Comment: try the fiddle if its giving results, that will give us better Idea

Comment: IE<9 we cant simply convert the image into dataURL , It will show error

Comment: @Backtrack I have updated one more link for the post, It may help with IE7 for above.