# Why can't I use a javascript function to paint more than one image on an html canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a javascript function like this:

```
function drawImage(canvas, image_source, dx, dy) {
  image = new Image();
  image.src = image_source;  
  image.onload = function() {
    c=canvas.getContext("2d");
    c.drawImage(image,dx,dy,100,100);
  }
}
```

When I call this function twice in a row, eg:

```
drawImage(canvas, "foo.jpg", 0, 0);
drawImage(canvas, "bar.jpg", 0 ,100);
```

bar gets painted twice, once at 0, and once at 100
If I switch the order so that foo is called last, foo gets painted twice.

I've tried to use an array for the images as in "c.drawImage(images[loaded++], dx, dy, 100, 100" and the two images paint separately, but their orders are random.

Is there any way to use a function like this to paint images on a canvas?

Comment: What browser/version are you using?  Perhaps its canvas element support is currently "beta"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing:

```
image = new Image();
```

to:

```
var image = new Image();
```

Currently you're setting "image" in the global scope, then potentially rewriting its onload handler before the load (which doesn't happen synchronously) has happened.

Comment: Note that you also should/must [set `onload` _before_ setting `src`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776670/should-setting-an-image-src-to-dataurl-be-available-immediately).

Comment: Good answer @Ben. Yes without var you're setting a global variable, which then gets overwritten by 'bar'.

Comment: Thanks Ben and everyone else for the comments.  Adding the var fixed the error.  Time to learn a bit more about scope in javascript.