# Use images created from canvas

Tags: javascript, drupal, html, canvas, ubercart

I know I can save the image from canvas using the canvas.toDataURL().  But how can i immediately use it?

Here's the scenario:

I have a shopping cart with a customizable product.  By changing attributes, I'm able to create a customized product image using canvas. Immediately after adding to cart, I want to use the generated canvas image as the cart thumbnail for the product added to cart.

How can I achieve this?  Can someone help me with an idea for the programming workflow to achieve this? I am using Drupal + Ubercart with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new image (either in script via `new Image` or as an element via `document.createElement("img")` and appending it to the DOM). If your cart already as an `<img>` element, then get a script reference to it instead.
2. (optional) Set the `onload` attribute of the image to a function, if you need to use it programmatically after it is ready.
3. Set the `src` of the image to your data URL.

For more information on the need to set `onload` before `src`, see
[Should setting an image src to data URL be available immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776670/should-setting-an-image-src-to-dataurl-be-available-immediately)

Comment: @Marvzz Has this answer not helped you? Do you have additional questions on this issue?

Comment: your answer made sense, sorry i just got back to the module just now. Ok, since we require that the generated image must be saved, I may need to store the data url on the database and retrieve later in a manner as u suggested.  Thanks, I'll get back here if i got stuck.