# getImageData() returning all zeros

Tags: javascript, canvas, getimagedata

I'm trying to output the pixel values from an image. The image is loading correctly; another answer on here suggested that the browswer is trying to read the pixels before the image is finished loading, but I can see that it's loaded by the time the alert() fires.

```
function initContext(canvasID, contextType)
{
   var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
   var context = canvas.getContext(contextType);
   return context;
}

function loadImage(imageSource, context)
{
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function()
    {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
    };
    imageObj.src = imageSource;
    return imageObj;
}

function readImage(imageData)
{
    console.log();
    console.log(imageData.data[0]);
}

var context = initContext('canvas','2d');
var imageObj = loadImage('images/color-test.png',context);
var imageData = context.getImageData(0,0,10,10);
alert();
readImage(imageData);
```

Comment: "loaded by the time the alert() fires" doesn't mean "loaded by the time `getImageData()` is called"

Comment: I moved the alert() to before the getImageData() call (Thanks, Paul!) and now it works. So it needed more time to load, I guess - only the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694599/getimagedata-always-returning-0) says to use an onload function to deal with that, and that's what I had. I'm not sure why it wasn't working.

Comment: You're calling `onload`, but not waiting for it to run. You're best off calling `getImageData()` and `readImage()` *from* the `onload` handler, to be sure it's done. Otherwise you're doomed once you remove the `alert()`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Image.onload()` is called asynchronously when the image has been loaded. That can happen after your current code calls `context.getImageData()`.

The following code should work:

```
function initContext(canvasID, contextType)
{
   var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
   var context = canvas.getContext(contextType);
   return context;
}

function loadImage(imageSource, context)
{
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function()
    {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
        var imageData = context.getImageData(0,0,10,10);
        readImage(imageData);
    };
    imageObj.src = imageSource;
    return imageObj;
}

function readImage(imageData)
{
    console.log();
    console.log(imageData.data[0]);
}

var context = initContext('canvas','2d');
var imageObj = loadImage('images/color-test.png',context);
```

If you want to access the `imageData` value outside of `loadImage()`, you have 2 basic choices:

1. Store the `imageData` in a variable that is declared outside the function. In this case, the value will be unset until your `onload()` is called, so the outside code would have to test it for reasonableness before calling `readImage(imageData)`.
2. Have the outside code register a callback function, and have your `onload()` call that function with the `imageData` value.

Comment: If I want to access imageData outside the loadImage function, what's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible you are evaluating a portion of an image that is transparent. I had this issue while scanning a PNG.

Answer (score 0):

Share a situation I encountered when I used a loop to request multiple images at the same time and get their pixels respectively. Then I encountered this problem.

```
//my code looks like this
for(let i = 0; i < urls.length; ++i){
    let img = new Image() // it will be destoryed every loop begin, even if use keyword 'var' insteads of 'let'.  
    img.onload = ()=>{
      let canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
      let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
      let imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1024, 1024) // imgData will be all 0 or some other unexpected result.
    }
    img.src = urls[i]
}

// fixed bug
window.imgs = []
for(let i = 0; i < urls.length; ++i)
    window.imgs[i] = new Image()
for(let i = 0; i < urls.length; ++i){
    let img = window.imgs[i]
    img.onload = ()=>{
      let canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
      let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
      let imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1024, 1024) 
    }
    img.src = urls[i]
}
```

The reason may be object reference, garbage collection and other problems. I don't know. Because I'm a beginner of js.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31589283)