# Issues onload() canvas with opera

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, onload-event

I make an application canvas. Every time I call draw () function, multiple images are drawn in canvas. The problem is that with Opera it does not work. Onload function does not always work.

```
    function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect (0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = srcvolets;
    img.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        if(srccouleur!=null){
            var img2 = new Image();
            img2.src = 'images/couleurs/'+volets+'/'+srccouleur+'.png';
            img2.onload = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                if(srcsculpture!=null){
                    var img3 = new Image();
                    img3.src = cheminsculpt+srcsculpture;
                    img3.onload = function(){
                        if(volets=='furno'){
                            ctx.drawImage(img3, 175, 235);
                        }else{
                            ctx.drawImage(img3, 175, 242);
                        }                           
                    }
                }
}}}}
```

Thank you. (Sorry for my English, I speak French)

Answer (score 2):

I think this has to do with images being cached, and the `onload` firing before it is set.

You might need to try setting `onload` before you set `src`.  See [this article about the problem](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/image-onload-isnt-being-called).

Comment: As noted in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776670/should-setting-an-image-src-to-dataurl-be-available-immediately), you _must_ set the `onload` before the `src` to avoid this issue (and another with IE9).