# Image drawn to HTML5 Canvas does not display correctly on first load

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm following a tutorial on importing and displaying images on an HTML5 canvas. Everything works fine, until I try to change the image itself. For example, I'll have a yellow circle as my image, and the script works fine. But if I open the image itself in Paint and change the circle to red, and refresh the page, the circle won't show up until I click or refresh again a second time manually. Here is the code snippet I'm using:

```
var topMap = new Image();
topMap.src = "topMap.png";

function drawMap() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    context.drawImage(topMap, 0, 0);
}

function init() {
    drawMap();
}

init();
```

Comment: browser caching, force a cache reload

Comment: It isn't browser caching, he just isn't waiting for the new image loading to finish

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The circle is probably not showing up because you are drawing it before the image is loaded. Change your last statement to:

```
// Lets not init until the image is actually done loading
topMap.onload = function() {
  init();
}
```

The reason it works after you hit refresh is because the image is now pre-loaded into the cache.

You always want to wait for any images to load before you attempt to draw them or nothing will show up on the canvas instead.

Comment: More simply, `topMap.onload = drawMap;`. Note that [you should set the `onload` _before_ you set `src`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776670/should-setting-an-image-src-to-dataurl-be-available-immediately). So: `var topMap = new Image; topMap.onload=drawMap; topMap.src="topMap.png";`

Comment: Make sure you heed Phrogz's advice here too!

Comment: Yes, here is exactly as I wrote it: `var topMap = new Image();
 topMap.onload=init;
 topMap.src = "topMap.png";`

Comment: This totally works... I was having the same problem with an Image. +1!