# Additive color on translucent dots

Tags: javascript, ruby, image-processing, css, canvas

I'm have a square icon, dimmed by a black mask.  There should be a number of dots on top of this mask, of various colors.  These dots are of addative color, so when on top of eachtother, they brighten.  In combination, enough of these these would turn the black mask multicolored or even white, revealing the image underneath.

How could this be done? Client-side, with canvas or css3? Server-side, with ImageMagick or something else?

Here's a link to additive color on canvas: http://contrapunctus.net/blog/2010/rgb-demo

Comment: It could be done "with code". Everything you listed is a possibility. Have you tried anything? What's your question, or are you asking someone to write it for you?

Comment: Sorry, I could've been specific.  I've never used canvas before, and am looking for someone to show me the api method necessary - rather than having to run around trying first one thing, then another..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 Canvas + [Context Blender](https://github.com/Phrogz/context-blender) + screen mode.

Or, as you linked, using additive global composite mode.

Or using ImageMagick.

Or using [ChunkyPNG](https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png) along with addition.

Comment: After playing with photoshop, I think I need to make a white layer with subtractive composting. This would color the image black.  In spots where this over-layer is darkened, the image shows through.  So then the dots need to darken eachother instead of lighten, and be inverted from the color desired.

Comment: I'm having trouble using context blender-- the overlay always appears below the image canvas, and I don't know why.  You can see the source, but it won't run due to cross domain issues: http://jsfiddle.net/pehrlich/a47bD/2/

Comment: @Peter Pare it down. Make a reproducible test case that has the absolute minimum amount of code necessary to show the problem. Make it actually run on JSFiddle. If you can delete HTML, CSS, or JS and the problem exists, you haven't fully pared it down. Either you'll have your "ah-HA!" moment in the process, or you'll end up with something that I can actually help you with. What you've pasted right now isn't even legal JavaScript, let alone working code showing the problem.

Comment: Here is a working fiddle (converted to js from coffee), the blue adds with the photo: http://jsfiddle.net/pehrlich/a47bD/3/
Here is a hosted version, with the same code, copy and pasted.  The blue goes behind the photo: http://minthatheater.com/canvas.html

Comment: Here's a simpler, modified version of your first fiddle, that works for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/a47bD/4/. I'll have to do extra work to see what your hosted version is doing differently.

Comment: In short, you need to [wait until the data-url is ready](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776670/should-setting-an-image-src-to-dataurl-be-available-immediately). If you change your last line of code to `setTimeout(function(){ ocontext.blendOnto(ucontext,'add')},5000)` it works correctly, while a delay of 1ms sometimes works and sometimes fails. If you wrap your code in `$('#image1').bind('load',function(){ ... });` it always works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10515/discussion-between-peter-ehrlich-and-phrogz)