# Use image for background of canvas

Tags: html

I am making the simple canvas application.

I want to use image for background of canvas.

I have found out that I should use drawImage(img,x,y).

This is my codes ,but drummap.img doesn't appear.

Where is wrong?

```
Test
<canvas id="leap-overlay"></canvas>
<script src="leap.js"></script>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("leap-overlay");

// fullscreen
canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;

// create a rendering context
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height);


var img = new Image();
img.src = "drummap.jpg";
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,100,100);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your image `drummap.jpg` is located in said directory, create the image, set the onload to use the new image, and *then* set the src ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4807114/2612112)):

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 100);
};

img.src = 'drummap.jpg';
```

Comment: Thanks @Campari,but it doesn't work.. and no error message on console. 'drummap.jpg' is located in the correct directory.

Comment: @whitebear What if you comment out your `ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)"` line. It might be drawing all black _on top_ of the image so you don't see it.

Comment: I quoted this from sample codes ,now I delete ctx.fillStyle sentence,but it doesn't change.

Comment: @whitebear That's strange because there's no error in your code as far I can tell. The only thing I can think of is that perhaps `drawImage` only takes 3 parameters. I've updated my answer now, see if it works.

Comment: @whitebear the problem with your code is that you translate everything and hide it. You are using `canvas.height` and maybe you want to centralize it with `height/2`. Remember that at the beginning you set the height to the size of the document.

Comment: @wendelbsilva I agree with this. Maybe the problem all along was that you _were_ drawing the image but where it can't be seen. Just comment out the `ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height);` line.

Comment: You guys are spot on. That canvas.height is causing him to draw outside the viewable area.

Comment: I agree the translate is messing it all up.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you're clearing your canvas or what your drawing, but remember your canvas is inherently transparent so feel free to give the canvas a css style background:

```
<canvas style = "background-image: url(pathtoyourimage.jpg);"></canvas>
```

Hope that helps.