# Base64 Encoded Image Not Showing Up

Tags: javascript, base64, onload, src, todataurl

I'm using a dataUrl and setting an image's src as the url but the image is not showing up when I do that. Space is created for the image but it's blank.

```
var rUrl = received.pngUrl;
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function(){

};   
image.src = rUrl;
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

[Should setting an image src to data URL be available immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776670/should-setting-an-image-src-to-data-url-be-available-immediately)

I saw this post about using image.onload. I tried setting image.src = rUrl inside the onload function but then it wouldn't execute. My rUrl is of the form "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAu4AAALu..."

Other relevant code:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
   var pickedImage = new Image();
   pickedImage.src = "{% static '/draw/hurricane.PNG' %}"
   pickedImage.onload = function() {
       context.drawImage(pickedImage, 0, 0);
   }
   var pngUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
   socket.send(JSON.stringify({pngUrl}));
});

socket.onmessage = function(receivedMessage) {
    var received = JSON.parse(receivedMessage.data);
    
    ...(code from above)...
}
```

I'm using this gray hurricane image. It should show under the car image and there's a blank space for it but I don't see the image. Dev tools shows there's an img src for it though.

Gray hurricane pic
[image: hurricane.png]

Dev Tools
[image: Dev Tools]

Image src is this. Is there anything wrong with it?

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAu4AAALuCAYAAADxHZPKAAAgAElEQVR4Xu3WQQ0AAAgDMfBvGhtcUhQsHY/tOAIECBAgQIAAAQIE3gvs+4QCEiBAgAABAgQIECAwhrsnIECAAAECBAgQIBAQMNwDJYlIgAABAgQIECBAwHD3AwQIECBAgAABAgQCAoZ7oCQRCRAgQIAAAQIECBjufoAAAQIECBAgQIBAQMBwD5QkIgECBAgQIECAAAHD3Q8QIECAAAECBAgQCAgY7oGSRCRAgAABAgQIECBguPsBAgQIECBAgAABAgEBwz1QkogECBAgQIAAAQIEDHc/QIAAAQIECBAgQCAgYLgHShKRAAECBAgQIECAgOHuBwgQIECAAAECBAgEBAz3QEkiEiBAgAABAgQIEDDc/QABAgQIECBAgACBgIDhHihJRAIECBAgQIAAAQKGux8gQIAAAQIECBAgEBAw3AMliUiAAAECBAgQIEDAcPcDBAgQIECAAAECBAIChnugJBEJECBAgAABAgQIGO5+gAABAgQIECBAgEBAwHAPlCQiAQIECBAgQIAAAcPdDxAgQIAAAQIECBAICBjugZJEJECAAAECBAgQIGC4+wECBAgQIECAAAECAQHDPVCSiAQIECBAgAABAgQMdz9AgAABAgQIECBAICBguAdKEpEAAQIECBAgQICA4e4HCBAgQIAAAQIECAQEDPdASSISIECAAAECBAgQMNz9AAECBAgQIECAAIGAgOEeKElEAgQIECBAgAABAoa7HyBAgAABAgQIECAQEDDcAyWJSIAAAQIECBAgQMBw9wMECBAgQIAAAQIEAgKGe6AkEQkQIECAAAECBAgY7n6AAAECBAgQIECAQEDAcA+UJCIBAgQIECBAgAABw90PECBAgAABAgQIEAgIGO6BkkQkQIAAAQIECBAgYLj7AQIECBAgQIAAAQIBAcM9UJKIBAgQIECAAAECBAx3P0CAAAECBAgQIEAgIGC4B0oSkQABAgQIECBAgIDh7gcIECBAgAABAgQIBAQM90BJIhIgQIAAAQIECBAw3P0AAQIECBAgQIAAgYCA4R4oSUQCBAgQIECAAAEChrsfIECAAAECBAgQIBAQMNwDJYlIgAABAgQIECBAwHD3AwQIECBAgAABAgQCAoZ7oCQRCRAgQIAAAQIECBjufoAAAQIECBAgQIBAQMBwD5QkIgECBAgQIECAAAHD3Q8QIECAAAECBAgQCAgY7oGSRCRAgAABAgQIECBguPsBAgQIECBAgAABAgEBwz1QkogECBAgQIAAAQIEDHc/QIAAAQIECBAgQCAgYLgHShKRAAECBAgQIECAgOHuBwgQIECAAAECBAgEBAz3QEkiEiBAgAABAgQIEDDc/QABAgQIECBAgACBgIDhHihJRAIECBAgQIAAAQKGux8gQIAAAQIECBAgEBAw3AMliUiAAAECBAgQIEDAcPcDBAgQIECAAAECBAIChnugJBEJECBAgAABAgQIGO5+gAABAgQIECBAgEBAwHAPlCQiAQIECBAgQIAAAcPdDxAgQIAAAQIECBAICBjugZJEJECAAAECBAgQIGC4+wECBAgQIECAAAECAQHDPVCSiAQIECBAgAABAgQMdz9AgAABAgQIECBAICBguAdKEpEAAQIECBAgQICA4e4HCBAgQIAAAQIECAQEDPdASSISIECAAAECBAgQMNz9AAECBAgQIECAAIGAgOEeKElEAgQIECBAgAABAoa7HyBAgAABAgQIECAQEDDcAyWJSIAAAQIECBAgQMBw9wMECBAgQIAAAQIEAgKGe6AkEQkQIECAAAECBAgY7n6AAAECBAgQIECAQEDAcA+UJCIBAgQIECBAgAABw90PECBAgAABAgQIEAgIGO6BkkQkQIAAAQIECBAgYLj7AQIECBAgQIAAAQIBAcM9UJKIBAgQIECAAAECBAx3P0CAAAECBAgQIEAgIGC4B0oSkQABAgQIECBAgIDh7gcIECBAgAABAgQIBAQM90BJIhIgQIAAAQIECBAw3P0AAQIECBAgQIAAgYCA4R4oSUQCBAgQIECAAAEChrsfIECAAAECBAgQIBAQMNwDJYlIgAABAgQIECBAwHD3AwQIECBAgAABAgQCAoZ7oCQRCRAgQIAAAQIECBjufoAAAQIECBAgQIBAQMBwD5QkIgECBAgQIECAAAHD3Q8QIECAAAECBAgQCAgY7oGSRCRAgAABAgQIECBguPsBAgQIECBAgAABAgEBwz1QkogECBAgQIAAAQIEDHc/QIAAAQIECBAgQCAgYLgHShKRAAECBAgQIECAgOHuBwgQIECAAAECBAgEBAz3QEkiEiBAgAABAgQIEDDc/QABAgQIECBAgACBgIDhHihJRAIECBAgQIAAAQKGux8gQIAAAQIECBAgEBAw3AMliUiAAAECBAgQIEDAcPcDBAgQIECAAAECBAIChnugJBEJECBAgAABAgQIGO5+gAABAgQIECBAgEBAwHAPlCQiAQIECBAgQIAAAcPdDxAgQIAAAQIECBAICBjugZJEJECAAAECBAgQIGC4+wECBAgQIECAAAECAQHDPVCSiAQIECBAgAABAgQMdz9AgAABAgQIECBAICBguAdKEpEAAQIECBAgQICA4e4HCBAgQIAAAQIECAQEDPdASSISIECAAAECBAgQMNz9AAECBAgQIECAAIGAgOEeKElEAgQIECBAgAABAoa7HyBAgAABAgQIECAQEDDcAyWJSIAAAQIECBAgQMBw9wMECBAgQIAAAQIEAgKGe6AkEQkQIECAAAECBAgY7n6AAAECBAgQIECAQEDAcA+UJCIBAgQIECBAgAABw90PECBAgAABAgQIEAgIGO6BkkQkQIAAAQIECBAgYLj7AQIECBAgQIAAAQIBAcM9UJKIBAgQIECAAAECBAx3P0CAAAECBAgQIEAgIGC4B0oSkQABAgQIECBAgIDh7gcIECBAgAABAgQIBAQM90BJIhIgQIAAAQIECBAw3P0AAQIECBAgQIAAgYCA4R4oSUQCBAgQIECAAAEChrsfIECAAAECBAgQIBAQMNwDJYlIgAABAgQIECBAwHD3AwQIECBAgAABAgQCAoZ7oCQRCRAgQIAAAQIECBjufoAAAQIECBAgQIBAQMBwD5QkIgECBAgQIECAAAHD3Q8QIECAAAECBAgQCAgY7oGSRCRAgAABAgQIECBguPsBAgQIECBAgAABAgEBwz1QkogECBAgQIAAAQIEDHc/QIAAAQIECBAgQCAgYLgHShKRAAECBAgQIECAgOHuBwgQIECAAAECBAgEBAz3QEkiEiBAgAABAgQIEDDc/QABAgQIECBAgACBgIDhHihJRAIECBAgQIAAAQKGux8gQIAAAQIECBAgEBAw3AMliUiAAAECBAgQIEDAcPcDBAgQIECAAAECBAIChnugJBEJECBAgAABAgQIGO5+gAABAgQIECBAgEBAwHAPlCQiAQIECBAgQIAAAcPdDxAgQIAAAQIECBAICBjugZJEJECAAAECBAgQIGC4+wECBAgQIECAAAECAQHDPVCSiAQIECBAgAABAgQMdz9AgAABAgQIECBAICBguAdKEpEAAQIECBAgQICA4e4HCBAgQIAAAQIECAQEDPdASSISIECAAAECBAgQMNz9AAECBAgQIECAAIGAgOEeKElEAgQIECBAgAABAoa7HyBAgAABAgQIECAQEDDcAyWJSIAAAQIECBAgQMBw9wMECBAgQIAAAQIEAgKGe6AkEQkQIECAAAECBAgY7n6AAAECBAgQIECAQEDAcA+UJCIBAgQIECBAgAABw90PECBAgAABAgQIEAgIGO6BkkQkQIAAAQIECBAgYLj7AQIECBAgQIAAAQIBAcM9UJKIBAgQIECAAAECBAx3P0CAAAECBAgQIEAgIGC4B0oSkQABAgQIECBAgIDh7gcIECBAgAABAgQIBAQM90BJIhIgQIAAAQIECBAw3P0AAQIECBAgQIAAgYCA4R4oSUQCBAgQIECAAAEChrsfIECAAAECBAgQIBAQMNwDJYlIgAABAgQIECBAwHD3AwQIECBAgAABAgQCAoZ7oCQRCRAgQIAAAQIECBjufoAAAQIECBAgQIBAQMBwD5QkIgECBAgQIECAAAHD3Q8QIECAAAECBAgQCAgY7oGSRCRAgAABAgQIECBguPsBAgQIECBAgAABAgEBwz1QkogECBAgQIAAAQIEDHc/QIAAAQIECBAgQCAgYLgHShKRAAECBAgQIECAgOHuBwgQIECAAAECBAgEBAz3QEkiEiBAgAABAgQIEDDc/QABAgQIECBAgACBgIDhHihJRAIECBAgQIAAAQKGux8gQIAAAQIECBAgEBAw3AMliUiAAAECBAgQIEDAcPcDBAgQIECAAAECBAIChnugJBEJECBAgAABAgQIGO5+gAABAgQIECBAgEBAwHAPlCQiAQIECBAgQIAAAcPdDxAgQIAAAQIECBAICBjugZJEJECAAAECBAgQIGC4+wECBAgQIECAAAECAQHDPVCSiAQIECBAgAABAgQMdz9AgAABAgQIECBAICBguAdKEpEAAQIECBAgQICA4e4HCBAgQIAAAQIECAQEDPdASSISIECAAAECBAgQMNz9AAECBAgQIECAAIGAgOEeKElEAgQIECBAgAABAoa7HyBAgAABAgQIECAQEDDcAyWJSIAAAQIECBAgQMBw9wMECBAgQIAAAQIEAgKGe6AkEQkQIECAAAECBAgY7n6AAAECBAgQIECAQEDAcA+UJCIBAgQIECBAgAABw90PECBAgAABAgQIEAgIGO6BkkQkQIAAAQIECBAgYLj7AQIECBAgQIAAAQIBAcM9UJKIBAgQIECAAAECBAx3P0CAAAECBAgQIEAgIGC4B0oSkQABAgQIECBAgIDh7gcIECBAgAABAgQIBAQM90BJIhIgQIAAAQIECBAw3P0AAQIECBAgQIAAgYCA4R4oSUQCBAgQIECAAAEChrsfIECAAAECBAgQIBAQMNwDJYlIgAABAgQIECBAwHD3AwQIECBAgAABAgQCAoZ7oCQRCRAgQIAAAQIECBjufoAAAQIECBAgQIBAQMBwD5QkIgECBAgQIECAAAHD3Q8QIECAAAECBAgQCAgY7oGSRCRAgAABAgQIECBguPsBAgQIECBAgAABAgEBwz1QkogECBAgQIAAAQIEDHc/QIAAAQIECBAgQCAgYLgHShKRAAECBAgQIECAgOHuBwgQIECAAAECBAgEBAz3QEkiEiBAgAABAgQIEDDc/QABAgQIECBAgACBgIDhHihJRAIECBAgQIAAAQKGux8gQIAAAQIECBAgEBAw3AMliUiAAAECBAgQIEDAcPcDBAgQIECAAAECBAIChnugJBEJECBAgAABAgQIGO5+gAABAgQIECBAgEBAwHAPlCQiAQIECBAgQIAAAcPdDxAgQIAAAQIECBAICBjugZJEJECAAAECBAgQIGC4+wECBAgQIECAAAECAQHDPVCSiAQIECBAgAABAgQMdz9AgAABAgQIECBAICBguAdKEpEAAQIECBAgQICA4e4HCBAgQIAAAQIECAQEDPdASSISIECAAAECBAgQMNz9AAECBAgQIECAAIGAgOEeKElEAgQIECBAgAABAoa7HyBAgAABAgQIECAQEDDcAyWJSIAAAQIECBAgQMBw9wMECBAgQIAAAQIEAgKGe6AkEQkQIECAAAECBAgY7n6AAAECBAgQIECAQEDAcA+UJCIBAgQIECBAgAABw90PECBAgAABAgQIEAgIGO6BkkQkQIAAAQIECBAgYLj7AQIECBAgQIAAAQIBAcM9UJKIBAgQIECAAAECBAx3P0CAAAECBAgQIEAgIGC4B0oSkQABAgQIECBAgIDh7gcIECBAgAABAgQIBAQM90BJIhIgQIAAAQIECBAw3P0AAQIECBAgQIAAgYCA4R4oSUQCBAgQIECAAAEChrsfIECAAAECBAgQIBAQMNwDJYlIgAABAgQIECBAwHD3AwQIECBAgAABAgQCAoZ7oCQRCRAgQIAAAQIECBjufoAAAQIECBAgQIBAQMBwD5QkIgECBAgQIECAAAHD3Q8QIECAAAECBAgQCAgY7oGSRCRAgAABAgQIECBguPsBAgQIECBAgAABAgEBwz1QkogECBAgQIAAAQIEDHc/QIAAAQIECBAgQCAgYLgHShKRAAECBAgQIECAgOHuBwgQIECAAAECBAgEBAz3QEkiEiBAgAABAgQIEDDc/QABAgQIECBAgACBgIDhHihJRAIECBAgQIAAAQKGux8gQIAAAQIECBAgEBAw3AMliUiAAAECBAgQIEDAcPcDBAgQIECAAAECBAIChnugJBEJECBAgAABAgQIGO5+gAABAgQIECBAgEBAwHAPlCQiAQIECBAgQIAAAcPdDxAgQIAAAQIECBAICBjugZJEJECAAAECBAgQIGC4+wECBAgQIECAAAECAQHDPVCSiAQIECBAgAABAgQMdz9AgAABAgQIECBAICBguAdKEpEAAQIECBAgQICA4e4HCBAgQIAAAQIECAQEDPdASSISIECAAAECBAgQMNz9AAECBAgQIECAAIGAgOEeKElEAgQIECBAgAABAoa7HyBAgAABAgQIECAQEDDcAyWJSIAAAQIECBAgQMBw9wMECBAgQIAAAQIEAgKGe6AkEQkQIECAAAECBAgY7n6AAAECBAgQIECAQEDAcA+UJCIBAgQIECBAgAABw90PECBAgAABAgQIEAgIGO6BkkQkQIAAAQIECBAgYLj7AQIECBAgQIAAAQIBAcM9UJKIBAgQIECAAAECBAx3P0CAAAECBAgQIEAgIGC4B0oSkQABAgQIECBAgIDh7gcIECBAgAABAgQIBAQM90BJIhIgQIAAAQIECBAw3P0AAQIECBAgQIAAgYCA4R4oSUQCBAgQIECAAAEChrsfIECAAAECBAgQIBAQMNwDJYlIgAABAgQIECBAwHD3AwQIECBAgAABAgQCAoZ7oCQRCRAgQIAAAQIECBjufoAAAQIECBAgQIBAQMBwD5QkIgECBAgQIECAAAHD3Q8QIECAAAECBAgQCAgY7oGSRCRAgAABAgQIECBguPsBAgQIECBAgAABAgEBwz1QkogECBAgQIAAAQIEDHc/QIAAAQIECBAgQCAgYLgHShKRAAECBAgQIECAgOHuBwgQIECAAAECBAgEBAz3QEkiEiBAgAABAgQIEDDc/QABAgQIECBAgACBgIDhHihJRAIECBAgQIAAAQKGux8gQIAAAQIECBAgEBAw3AMliUiAAAECBAgQIEDAcPcDBAgQIECAAAECBAIChnugJBEJECBAgAABAgQIGO5+gAABAgQIECBAgEBAwHAPlCQiAQIECBAgQIAAAcPdDxAgQIAAAQIECBAICBjugZJEJECAAAECBAgQIGC4+wECBAgQIECAAAECAQHDPVCSiAQIECBAgAABAgQMdz9AgAABAgQIECBAICBguAdKEpEAAQIECBAgQICA4e4HCBAgQIAAAQIECAQEDPdASSISIECAAAECBAgQMNz9AAECBAgQIECAAIGAgOEeKElEAgQIECBAgAABAoa7HyBAgAABAgQIECAQEDDcAyWJSIAAAQIECBAgQMBw9wMECBAgQIAAAQIEAgKGe6AkEQkQIECAAAECBAgY7n6AAAECBAgQIECAQEDAcA+UJCIBAgQIECBAgAABw90PECBAgAABAgQIEAgIGO6BkkQkQIAAAQIECBAgYLj7AQIECBAgQIAAAQIBAcM9UJKIBAgQIECAAAECBAx3P0CAAAECBAgQIEAgIGC4B0oSkQABAgQIECBAgIDh7gcIECBAgAABAgQIBAQM90BJIhIgQIAAAQIECBAw3P0AAQIECBAgQIAAgYCA4R4oSUQCBAgQIECAAAEChrsfIECAAAECBAgQIBAQMNwDJYlIgAABAgQIECBAwHD3AwQIECBAgAABAgQCAoZ7oCQRCRAgQIAAAQIECBjufoAAAQIECBAgQIBAQMBwD5QkIgECBAgQIECAAAHD3Q8QIECAAAECBAgQCAgY7oGSRCRAgAABAgQIECBguPsBAgQIECBAgAABAgEBwz1QkogECBAgQIAAAQIEDHc/QIAAAQIECBAgQCAgYLgHShKRAAECBAgQIECAgOHuBwgQIECAAAECBAgEBAz3QEkiEiBAgAABAgQIEDDc/QABAgQIECBAgACBgIDhHihJRAIECBAgQIAAAQKGux8gQIAAAQIECBAgEBAw3AMliUiAAAECBAgQIEDAcPcDBAgQIECAAAECBAIChnugJBEJECBAgAABAgQIGO5+gAABAgQIECBAgEBAwHAPlCQiAQIECBAgQIAAAcPdDxAgQIAAAQIECBAICBjugZJEJECAAAECBAgQIGC4+wECBAgQIECAAAECAQHDPVCSiAQIECBAgAABAgQMdz9AgAABAgQIECBAICBguAdKEpEAAQIECBAgQICA4e4HCBAgQIAAAQIECAQEDPdASSISIECAAAECBAgQMNz9AAECBAgQIECAAIGAgOEeKElEAgQIECBAgAABAoa7HyBAgAABAgQIECAQEDDcAyWJSIAAAQIECBAgQMBw9wMECBAgQIAAAQIEAgKGe6AkEQkQIECAAAECBAgY7n6AAAECBAgQIECAQEDAcA+UJCIBAgQIECBAgAABw90PECBAgAABAgQIEAgIGO6BkkQkQIAAAQIECBAgYLj7AQIECBAgQIAAAQIBAcM9UJKIBAgQIECAAAECBAx3P0CAAAECBAgQIEAgIGC4B0oSkQABAgQIECBAgIDh7gcIECBAgAABAgQIBAQM90BJIhIgQIAAAQIECBAw3P0AAQIECBAgQIAAgYCA4R4oSUQCBAgQIECAAAEChrsfIECAAAECBAgQIBAQMNwDJYlIgAABAgQIECBAwHD3AwQIECBAgAABAgQCAoZ7oCQRCRAgQIAAAQIECBjufoAAAQIECBAgQIBAQMBwD5QkIgECBAgQIECAAAHD3Q8QIECAAAECBAgQCAgY7oGSRCRAgAABAgQIECBguPsBAgQIECBAgAABAgEBwz1QkogECBAgQIAAAQIEDHc/QIAAAQIECBAgQCAgYLgHShKRAAECBAgQIECAgOHuBwgQIECAAAECBAgEBAz3QEkiEiBAgAABAgQIEDDc/QABAgQIECBAgACBgIDhHihJRAIECBAgQIAAAQKGux8gQIAAAQIECBAgEBAw3AMliUiAAAECBAgQIEDAcPcDBAgQIECAAAECBAIChnugJBEJECBAgAABAgQIGO5+gAABAgQIECBAgEBAwHAPlCQiAQIECBAgQIAAAcPdDxAgQIAAAQIECBAICBjugZJEJECAAAECBAgQIGC4+wECBAgQIECAAAECAQHDPVCSiAQIECBAgAABAgQMdz9AgAABAgQIECBAICBguAdKEpEAAQIECBAgQICA4e4HCBAgQIAAAQIECAQEDPdASSISIECAAAECBAgQMNz9AAECBAgQIECAAIGAgOEeKElEAgQIECBAgAABAoa7HyBAgAABAgQIECAQEDDcAyWJSIAAAQIECBAgQMBw9wMECBAgQIAAAQIEAgKGe6AkEQkQIECAAAECBAgY7n6AAAECBAgQIECAQEDAcA+UJCIBAgQIECBAgAABw90PECBAgAABAgQIEAgIGO6BkkQkQIAAAQIECBAgYLj7AQIECBAgQIAAAQIBAcM9UJKIBAgQIECAAAECBAx3P0CAAAECBAgQIEAgIGC4B0oSkQABAgQIECBAgIDh7gcIECBAgAABAgQIBAQM90BJIhIgQIAAAQIECBAw3P0AAQIECBAgQIAAgYCA4R4oSUQCBAgQIECAAAEChrsfIECAAAECBAgQIBAQMNwDJYlIgAABAgQIECBAwHD3AwQIECBAgAABAgQCAoZ7oCQRCRAgQIAAAQIECBjufoAAAQIECBAgQIBAQMBwD5QkIgECBAgQIECAAAHD3Q8QIECAAAECBAgQCAgY7oGSRCRAgAABAgQIECBguPsBAgQIECBAgAABAgEBwz1QkogECBAgQIAAAQIEDHc/QIAAAQIECBAgQCAgYLgHShKRAAECBAgQIECAgOHuBwgQIECAAAECBAgEBAz3QEkiEiBAgAABAgQIEDDc/QABAgQIECBAgACBgIDhHihJRAIECBAgQIAAAQKGux8gQIAAAQIECBAgEBAw3AMliUiAAAECBAgQIEDAcPcDBAgQIECAAAECBAIChnugJBEJECBAgAABAgQIGO5+gAABAgQIECBAgEBAwHAPlCQiAQIECBAgQIAAAcPdDxAgQIAAAQIECBAICBjugZJEJECAAAECBAgQIGC4+wECBAgQIECAAAECAQHDPVCSiAQIECBAgAABAgQMdz9AgAABAgQIECBAICBguAdKEpEAAQIECBAgQICA4e4HCBAgQIAAAQIECAQEDPdASSISIECAAAECBAgQMNz9AAECBAgQIECAAIGAgOEeKElEAgQIECBAgAABAoa7HyBAgAABAgQIECAQEDDcAyWJSIAAAQIECBAgQMBw9wMECBAgQIAAAQIEAgKGe6AkEQkQIECAAAECBAgY7n6AAAECBAgQIECAQEDAcA+UJCIBAgQIECBAgAABw90PECBAgAABAgQIEAgIGO6BkkQkQIAAAQIECBAgYLj7AQIECBAgQIAAAQIBAcM9UJKIBAgQIECAAAECBAx3P0CAAAECBAgQIEAgIGC4B0oSkQABAgQIECBAgIDh7gcIECBAgAABAgQIBAQM90BJIhIgQIAAAQIECBAw3P0AAQIECBAgQIAAgYCA4R4oSUQCBAgQIECAAAEChrsfIECAAAECBAgQIBAQMNwDJYlIgAABAgQIECBAwHD3AwQIECBAgAABAgQCAoZ7oCQRCRAgQGZzsosAAAz3SURBVIAAAQIECBjufoAAAQIECBAgQIBAQMBwD5QkIgECBAgQIECAAAHD3Q8QIECAAAECBAgQCAgY7oGSRCRAgAABAgQIECBguPsBAgQIECBAgAABAgEBwz1QkogECBAgQIAAAQIEDHc/QIAAAQIECBAgQCAgYLgHShKRAAECBAgQIECAgOHuBwgQIECAAAECBAgEBAz3QEkiEiBAgAABAgQIEDDc/QABAgQIECBAgACBgIDhHihJRAIECBAgQIAAAQKGux8gQIAAAQIECBAgEBAw3AMliUiAAAECBAgQIEDAcPcDBAgQIECAAAECBAIChnugJBEJECBAgAABAgQIGO5+gAABAgQIECBAgEBAwHAPlCQiAQIECBAgQIAAAcPdDxAgQIAAAQIECBAICBjugZJEJECAAAECBAgQIGC4+wECBAgQIECAAAECAQHDPVCSiAQIECBAgAABAgQMdz9AgAABAgQIECBAICBguAdKEpEAAQIECBAgQICA4e4HCBAgQIAAAQIECAQEDPdASSISIECAAAECBAgQMNz9AAECBAgQIECAAIGAgOEeKElEAgQIECBAgAABAoa7HyBAgAABAgQIECAQEDDcAyWJSIAAAQIECBAgQMBw9wMECBAgQIAAAQIEAgKGe6AkEQkQIECAAAECBAgY7n6AAAECBAgQIECAQEDAcA+UJCIBAgQIECBAgAABw90PECBAgAABAgQIEAgIGO6BkkQkQIAAAQIECBAgYLj7AQIECBAgQIAAAQIBAcM9UJKIBAgQIECAAAECBAx3P0CAAAECBAgQIEAgIGC4B0oSkQABAgQIECBAgIDh7gcIECBAgAABAgQIBAQM90BJIhIgQIAAAQIECBAw3P0AAQIECBAgQIAAgYCA4R4oSUQCBAgQIECAAAEChrsfIECAAAECBAgQIBAQMNwDJYlIgAABAgQIECBAwHD3AwQIECBAgAABAgQCAoZ7oCQRCRAgQIAAAQIECBjufoAAAQIECBAgQIBAQMBwD5QkIgECBAgQIECAAAHD3Q8QIECAAAECBAgQCAgY7oGSRCRAgAABAgQIECBguPsBAgQIECBAgAABAgEBwz1QkogECBAgQIAAAQIEDHc/QIAAAQIECBAgQCAgYLgHShKRAAECBAgQIECAgOHuBwgQIECAAAECBAgEBAz3QEkiEiBAgAABAgQIEDDc/QABAgQIECBAgACBgIDhHihJRAIECBAgQIAAAQKGux8gQIAAAQIECBAgEBAw3AMliUiAAAECBAgQIEDAcPcDBAgQIECAAAECBAIChnugJBEJECBAgAABAgQIGO5+gAABAgQIECBAgEBAwHAPlCQiAQIECBAgQIAAAcPdDxAgQIAAAQIECBAICBjugZJEJECAAAECBAgQIGC4+wECBAgQIECAAAECAQHDPVCSiAQIECBAgAABAgQMdz9AgAABAgQIECBAICBguAdKEpEAAQIECBAgQICA4e4HCBAgQIAAAQIECAQEDPdASSISIECAAAECBAgQMNz9AAECBAgQIECAAIGAgOEeKElEAgQIECBAgAABAoa7HyBAgAABAgQIECAQEDDcAyWJSIAAAQIECBAgQMBw9wMECBAgQIAAAQIEAgKGe6AkEQkQIECAAAECBAgY7n6AAAECBAgQIECAQEDAcA+UJCIBAgQIECBAgAABw90PECBAgAABAgQIEAgIGO6BkkQkQIAAAQIECBAgYLj7AQIECBAgQIAAAQIBAcM9UJKIBAgQIECAAAECBAx3P0CAAAECBAgQIEAgIGC4B0oSkQABAgQIECBAgIDh7gcIECBAgAABAgQIBAQM90BJIhIgQIAAAQIECBAw3P0AAQIECBAgQIAAgYCA4R4oSUQCBAgQIECAAAEChrsfIECAAAECBAgQIBAQMNwDJYlIgAABAgQIECBAwHD3AwQIECBAgAABAgQCAoZ7oCQRCRAgQIAAAQIECBjufoAAAQIECBAgQIBAQMBwD5QkIgECBAgQIECAAAHD3Q8QIECAAAECBAgQCAgY7oGSRCRAgAABAgQIECBguPsBAgQIECBAgAABAgEBwz1QkogECBAgQIAAAQIEDHc/QIAAAQIECBAgQCAgYLgHShKRAAECBAgQIECAgOHuBwgQIECAAAECBAgEBAz3QEkiEiBAgAABAgQIEDDc/QABAgQIECBAgACBgIDhHihJRAIECBAgQIAAAQKGux8gQIAAAQIECBAgEBAw3AMliUiAAAECBAgQIEDAcPcDBAgQIECAAAECBAIChnugJBEJECBAgAABAgQIGO5+gAABAgQIECBAgEBAwHAPlCQiAQIECBAgQIAAAcPdDxAgQIAAAQIECBAICBjugZJEJECAAAECBAgQIGC4+wECBAgQIECAAAECAQHDPVCSiAQIECBAgAABAgQMdz9AgAABAgQIECBAICBguAdKEpEAAQIECBAgQICA4e4HCBAgQIAAAQIECAQEDPdASSISIECAAAECBAgQMNz9AAECBAgQIECAAIGAgOEeKElEAgQIECBAgAABAoa7HyBAgAABAgQIECAQEDDcAyWJSIAAAQIECBAgQMBw9wMECBAgQIAAAQIEAgKGe6AkEQkQIECAAAECBAgY7n6AAAECBAgQIECAQEDAcA+UJCIBAgQIECBAgAABw90PECBAgAABAgQIEAgIGO6BkkQkQIAAAQIECBAgYLj7AQIECBAgQIAAAQIBAcM9UJKIBAgQIECAAAECBAx3P0CAAAECBAgQIEAgIGC4B0oSkQABAgQIECBAgIDh7gcIECBAgAABAgQIBAQM90BJIhIgQIAAAQIECBAw3P0AAQIECBAgQIAAgYCA4R4oSUQCBAgQIECAAAEChrsfIECAAAECBAgQIBAQMNwDJYlIgAABAgQIECBAwHD3AwQIECBAgAABAgQCAoZ7oCQRCRAgQIAAAQIECBjufoAAAQIECBAgQIBAQMBwD5QkIgECBAgQIECAAAHD3Q8QIECAAAECBAgQCAgY7oGSRCRAgAABAgQIECBguPsBAgQIECBAgAABAgEBwz1QkogECBAgQIAAAQIEDHc/QIAAAQIECBAgQCAgYLgHShKRAAECBAgQIECAgOHuBwgQIECAAAECBAgEBAz3QEkiEiBAgAABAgQIEDDc/QABAgQIECBAgACBgIDhHihJRAIECBAgQIAAAQKGux8gQIAAAQIECBAgEBAw3AMliUiAAAECBAgQIEDAcPcDBAgQIECAAAECBAIChnugJBEJECBAgAABAgQIGO5+gAABAgQIECBAgEBAwHAPlCQiAQIECBAgQIAAAcPdDxAgQIAAAQIECBAICBjugZJEJECAAAECBAgQIGC4+wECBAgQIECAAAECAQHDPVCSiAQIECBAgAABAgQMdz9AgAABAgQIECBAICBguAdKEpEAAQIECBAgQICA4e4HCBAgQIAAAQIECAQEDPdASSISIECAAAECBAgQMNz9AAECBAgQIECAAIGAgOEeKElEAgQIECBAgAABAoa7HyBAgAABAgQIECAQEDDcAyWJSIAAAQIECBAgQMBw9wMECBAgQIAAAQIEAgKGe6AkEQkQIECAAAECBAgY7n6AAAECBAgQIECAQEDAcA+UJCIBAgQIECBAgAABw90PECBAgAABAgQIEAgIGO6BkkQkQIAAAQIECBAgYLj7AQIECBAgQIAAAQIBAcM9UJKIBAgQIECAAAECBAx3P0CAAAECBAgQIEAgIGC4B0oSkQABAgQIECBAgIDh7gcIECBAgAABAgQIBAQM90BJIhIgQIAAAQIECBAw3P0AAQIECBAgQIAAgYCA4R4oSUQCBAgQIECAAAEChrsfIECAAAECBAgQIBAQMNwDJYlIgAABAgQIECBAwHD3AwQIECBAgAABAgQCAoZ7oCQRCRAgQIAAAQIECBjufoAAAQIECBAgQIBAQMBwD5QkIgECBAgQIECAAAHD3Q8QIECAAAECBAgQCAgY7oGSRCRAgAABAgQIECBguPsBAgQIECBAgAABAgEBwz1QkogECBAgQIAAAQIEDHc/QIAAAQIECBAgQCAgYLgHShKRAAECBAgQIECAgOHuBwgQIECAAAECBAgEBAz3QEkiEiBAgAABAgQIEDDc/QABAgQIECBAgACBgIDhHihJRAIECBAgQIAAAQKGux8gQIAAAQIECBAgEBAw3AMliUiAAAECBAgQIEDAcPcDBAgQIECAAAECBAIChnugJBEJECBAgAABAgQIGO5+gAABAgQIECBAgEBAwHAPlCQiAQIECBAgQIAAAcPdDxAgQIAAAQIECBAICBjugZJEJECAAAECBAgQIGC4+wECBAgQIECAAAECAQHDPVCSiAQIECBAgAABAgQMdz9AgAABAgQIECBAICBguAdKEpEAAQIECBAgQIDAAV7aAu+Tv8m4AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

Comment: Is your Base64 correct? I tested your code with a random encoded image and worked perfectly. A little bit more concept might help us to resolve your problem. Provide more code parts if it's possible.

Comment: @NagySzabolcs okay added. Hmm I'm not sure then. The image src links to a white/blank image when I click on it in inspect.

Comment: And what does your dev tools console say?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans added

Comment: No, remember: [don't post pictures of text: post that text](/help/how-to-ask), but remember to only post what's relevant: are there console errors? If so, post those. Things that work as expected, you don't need to add to your post. Also, at this point you've strayed well outside of [mcve] territory: you want to rein that back in a little.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that base64 code doesn't work for me either. I converted that image into base64 and worked fine. Maybe there is something wrong with your converter. Try to convert your image with a different one. [Here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-convert-image-to-the-base64-string) is an example for that.

Anyway, the relevant code you attached is not the best, a lot of things missing from that. As others linked before, there are some basic tutorials on how to ask efficiently. I recommend [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to make a basic variation of your codes so we can edit it and we'll find solution faster.

I hope I could help!

Comment: I guess my picture was the problem. Idk why. Using a pic from webrtc-capture worked with my code.

Comment: Maybe you're getting the wrong base64 with that convertion. Try to use another function for that, like the one I suggested. I hope your problem will be resolved with that!